# Converting cisco PIX to cisco ASA

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-pix

I am about to migrate PIX 515E, 6.3(4), configuration to Cisco ASA.

I do not have the PIX which is in Paris, I have the configuration on a notepad file. I do not know the Cisco ASA model yet either which is going to be delivered on next week.

I have not done that before and the company is in a rush.

What issues should I be concerned about before starting?

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/37439) which seems to give a good bg. I upgraded a PIX last year to latest ios and then migrated to ASA and seem to remember that the tools provided were really good and that the rules were brought across without incident. The most important thing is to make sure you have backups in place before doing anything!

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to upgrade the asdm[version].bin if you are using CSM.

[Upgrade procedure](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a008067e9f9.shtml)